# Beta metric charts

Tags: discussion

Below are some charts for various beta site metrics against number of days since private beta launch.

- The scripts I am using to automate this is still experimental.
- The charts will be updated (hopefully) every day.
- Pardon me for the small number of data points, it will increase over time.
- You can also expect the formatting to improve, I don't adore how it currently looks either.

Suggestions are welcome :-)

[image]

<s>Note: the charts are updated through Google Drive, but I will make dummy edits to mark the latest update time.</s>

**Update:** added dotted lines in place of solid lines to indicate where consecutive data points are more than 7 days apart.

Comment: cㅇㅇl pictures .....

Comment: @user17915 You mean ㄷㅇㅇㅣ ?

Comment: The graphs look too small. Can you separate them one by one and post it as an answer so that they can be enlarged? Is it even possible?

Comment: @Rathony I think this is as large as it gets :-)

Comment: @Rathony By the way I don't think there's a size difference between questions and answers.

Comment: @busukxuan Wow, you performed a magic! They look far bigger and better.

Comment: They make look better if each graph was in a separate answer rather than in the question itself.

Comment: @Chenmunka Thanks for your suggestion, but I think keeping them all in the question body makes it neater, plus others can start discussions with answers. I know the size is a problem, but they are only just right on mobile. I will find other ways to improve it. Anyway, thanks :-)

Comment: do you have to manually update the graph every day, or can this be done automatically? Would you mind sharing how you do this kind of stuff?

Comment: @user17915 I wrote a program to 1) collect data from the Area51 site 2) make a graph from the data 3) update the image file on google drive with the freshly plotted one. Even the running of this program can be automated, but my Internet connection has been crappy these few days so I still run the program manually. I also make dummy edits after the graph is updated just to mark the update time in the question (but this can be automated too, just not doing it yet).

Comment: wow thanks for your effort. when you say you wrote a program, is this a feature provided by stackexchange itself?

Comment: is this what we should use to get data from stackexchange? http://data.stackexchange.com/korean/query/new

Comment: @user17915 You can use that if you want to use [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) to make a database query, or you can use the Stack Exchange API if you want to programmatically request data from the server, but I just made my program download the Area51 page and extract the metrics from the HTML.

Comment: @busukxuan: http://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api

Comment: is this where I should be looking for to find out how to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: @user17915 Yeah, I think so, though I went straight for the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Also if you don't want to deal with the web programming stuff you can use wrappers. Not sure if there's any for your language tho.

Comment: @busukxuan I really appreciate your efforts, but If you have to update this post on a daily basis, please consider stopping it. This site is all about learning the Korean language, not about statistics. Please consider asking questions and answering them if you really want to help this site. We can manage with the stats on Area 51. Also, you need to note that this site will never be closed even if we have 0.5 questions per day. Those stats don't matter unless the number of questions per day exceeds 10 per day.

Comment: @Rathony Well, sorry to tell you, but I don't currently have much more time than the one minute I use to update the post. I should have more time to participate after a few weeks :-)

Comment: Are these still being updated daily? I'd like to make them a featured post but they look like they may currently be a tiny bit behind.... just making sure they haven't stopped!

Comment: @topomorto Omg I totally forgot... Anyway, I just made it automatic so it should be updated daily now.

Comment: @busukxuan excellent thanks!

Comment: What was the impact of the great site stats disaster of 2018 on these? For now these are actually the only source of genuine historical data, so thanks one more time.

Comment: @topomorto Unfortunately I do not have the data for the site stats disaster. I reinstalled my Linux so I guess the automated `cron` job was gone. Anyway it should be working again now, and I added dotted lines to indicate the gap period with no data.

Comment: @busukxuan top stuff! Thanks. It's great even just to have the old stats here.

Comment: Hi - are these still alive?

Comment: @topomorto Not at the moment, it has been down for about 2 months now. There is a packaging issue on Fedora with a dependency that my script needs, so it can't run properly. IDK when it will be fixed. That said I just manually collected today's data (no new charts tho) so it might help bridge the gap a little in the future.

Comment: @busukxuan thanks. If they ever get fixed, great - if not, maybe you could put up the scripts somewhere (github?) in case someone wants to take them over? In any case, thanks for making these - they were interesting while they were up!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the graphs. I don't need to visit Area51 stats any more thanks to your efforts. .

Can we consider deleting the charts for *Answer rate* which will always hover around 100%, *Answer ratio* which will always be around 1.8 to 2, *Avid users* which will not fluctuate very much on a daily basis?

I think they are taking up too much space in the question.

Comment: I will consider making those optional, and choose not to use it for our site. Besides that I can cut the lower portion of the answer rate graph, and reduce the height of those with low data resolution, since e.g. no use being able to clearly differentiate a 0.05 difference when the answer ratios can only differ by multiples of 0.1. What do you think?

Comment: Also, I just reduced the width so that it doesn't feel too "bulky", but I'm not sure, does that help at all?

Comment: Well, I don't think the three graphs are really necessary. We have seen only 5 avid users increase during the period and I am not sure the graph is as meaningful as others. I am pretty sure that the answer ratio and rate will never change for the next few months.

Comment: Yes, you have your point, but I intend to share this program that generates the charts so that people from other betas can make use of it. I'm not that sure it's the same for them, that's why I said I will consider making those optional, rather than outright removing them, and then opt-out for our site. I'll remove them, but only until I find a solution. After that I'll put it back into the program, but I can opt those out for our site if they still get in the way. Your feedback is appreciated :-)

Comment: FWIW, this question will be read only by a very small number of people who need this information from time to time. It's up to you.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you said the graphs were too small, a screen of what size/dimensions were you using?

Comment: @busukxuan Thanks for the edit. It reads far better than before.

Comment: So what kind of screen were you using when you said they were too small? I need to consider different screen sizes because it might look different on every device.