# Our 1000th Question

Tags: discussion, community

Congratulations to our user [@CreativiTimothy](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/2034/creativitimothy) on asking our [1000th question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/why-does-%E3%84%B4-sometimes-sound-like-%E3%84%B7-first-position-such-as-in-%EB%84%88%EC%9D%98)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A great milestone to hit! Hopefully [our growing visitor numbers](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/beta-metric-charts) show that this site already represents a useful resource for Korean learners.

We've made it to 천(千) - next stop, 만(萬) ! Let's all remember to keep asking any good questions we can think of.